# How to use plain Ruby object with url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am rendering a page from a simple custom model (not ActiveRecord, plain ActiveModel) and I cannot get the url/path helpers to generate an url with their id, like this:

```
person_path(model)
# I want: /person/3
# I get: /person
```

Is there any concrete class I must inherit or function to implement so the url helpers work with my custom model?

I heard about `to_param` but it is not working, at least not with this:

```
  class Person
    include ActiveModel::Model 

    def id
      3
    end

    def to_param
      id.to_s
    end
  end
```

According [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) that should work:

> Any class that includes ActiveModel::Model can be used with form_for,
>   render and any other Action View helper methods, just like Active
>   Record objects.

But I guess there is still a missing function needed for the url helpers to work

Comment: Defining `to_param` should work. How did you try to implement the method?

Comment: nope, that is what I mentioned in the question. But I've just added a small sample of how I expected `to_param` to work

Comment: The code is correct, it should work. Please check that you have `resources :people` in your `routes.rb` file - I copied the exact model code you've posted, and `person_path(Person.new)` gets me `/people/3`, not just '/people'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you can share the code from `config/routes.rb` or at least the result from `rake routes`.

Double check your routes again. I think you may have defined the route as a singular resource `resource :person` which will not add an ID to the url.

Comment: argghhh! I knew those routes looked somehow different... they all were missing the (:id) part

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a `persisted?` method that returns `true`: the default implementation always returns false, which causes rails to generate a path  with no id.

Comment: Thank you! Lost about an hour looking for an explanation and nobody points out that `persistent?`  is important or when should one use it.